# A function reference is invoking a subroutine

Tags: fortran, subroutine

I have CERN program which calculates the gamma function of complex argument, but I can't run the program because of lack of Fortran knowledge.

I have the following program:

```
PROGRAM Console1
  IMPLICIT REAL *8 (A-H,O-Z) 
  COMPLEX *16 gama,z,w 
  z=cmplx(0,0.707106781186548d0) 
  gama=cgamma(0,z,w) 
END

SUBROUTINE cgamma(mo, z, w) 
  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: dp = SELECTED_REAL_KIND(14, 60)
  INTEGER, INTENT(IN)       :: mo
  COMPLEX (dp), INTENT(IN)  :: z
  COMPLEX (dp), INTENT(OUT) :: w
... the subroutine code here 
END SUBROUTINE cgamma
```

and then error appears

> error #6553: A function reference is invoking a subroutine subprogram. [CGAMMA]

Comment: What do you have? A .exe, or .so or what?

Comment: It's a .f90 I added the program.

Comment: Don't use `IMPLICIT` other the `IMPLICIT NONE`. Look at the subroutine code how variables should be defined. You are asking for A LOT of trouble by using `IMPLICIT REAL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the error message:

> A function reference is invoking a subroutine subprogram.

```
SUBROUTINE cgamma(mo, z, w)
END SUBROUTINE
```

defines `cgamma` as a (in this case external) subroutine.

In the program

```
gama=cgamma(0,z,w)
```

references `cgamma` as a function (returning a result to be assigned to `gama`).  This is the incompatibility to which the error message refers.

To resolve this you need to reference the subroutine with a `call` statement, or change `cgamma` to be a function, returning an appropriate result.

Given the design of the procedure (three arguments) I'd expect the function is intended.

Comment: Thanks, I just needed to write:
`call cgamma`
instead of 
`gama=cgamma`.
Thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

technically it is not a program.
I will repost part of the document in your link below, notice the `SUBROUTINE cgamma` and `END SUBROUTINE cgamma` as the very **first** and very **last** lines.  Technically this file is not a fortran program, it is only a subroutine which is part of a larger program.

```
SUBROUTINE cgamma(mo, z, w)

   IMPLICIT NONE

!  variables and code not worth posting to illustrate what is happening

   60 w = CMPLX(w1, w2, KIND=dp)
   RETURN

   70 w = (0.0_dp, 0.0_dp)
   RETURN

   CONTAINS

   FUNCTION rexp(x) RESULT(fn_val)
!     extra code here, do not need to post it
      fn_val = -1.0_dp
      RETURN
   END FUNCTION rexp

END SUBROUTINE cgamma
```

In fortran the first and last lines of the file would be `PROGRAM whatever` and `END`.

so you will either need to get the full program and use that which calls this cgamma subroutine,  or write your own fortran `PROGRAM` which then calls this `cgamma` subroutine.

Comment: Thanks for advice, I did it